# DHIS 2 Tracker capture dashboard Timeline Data Entry sorting

Tags: dhis2

With dhis 2.25, in the tracker capture dashboard, in the section "Timeline Data Entry", if you have more than one event for the same day, it is sorted by alphabetic, is it possible to have it sorted with the event time?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, we are not storing time-stamp only date. So the maximum we can do is sort by date - which we are doing currently.

We have plan to handle time-stamp / timezone in the future.